# Url Rewriting not working with cakephp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have an application , stored in a sub directory of my domain  v2. I have set up my .htaccess file as follows (in the directory mydomain.com)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/$1 [L]
```

In my knowledge my urls should be rewritten so they don't contain the /v2 in them.
Which does not happen , when I check the value of `$this->base` and `$this->webroot` it is www.mydomain.com/v2
when it should be just www.mydomain.com, Is there any way I can change this value.

So What I want to achieve is to rewrite urls so `www.mydomain.com/v2/products` appears in address bar as http://mydomain.com/products

Answer (score 0):

The only thing those rules do is take a request for `www.mydomain.com/products` and internally serve the resource at `/v2/products`. It doesn't do anything about "changing" the URL on the browser. To do that you must *redirect*:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /v2/([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

And include that along with the rules that you have.

Comment: Not Working!...Any ideas Why :S ??